# End-of-line conversion during Input/Output for text files

Tags: file-io, rust, newline

How to write strings (`&str` and `String`) containing newlines to text files?

In `C` you can switch between writing text as is or converting `'\n'` to proper end of line symbol for the OS via `fopen` flags, `"w"` or `"wb"`. For example in Windows `'\n'` is converted to `"\r\n"` during I/O.

How can I achieve this with Rust? I cannot find corresponding API in `std::fs::File`.

Comment: How broad are you expecting the conversions to be? From all possible line-endings in-memory to the system line endings in the file? Are you hoping to do the opposite when reading the file? Rust doesn't have "text mode" files like C does, so it'd be your responsibility to do it before writing the data or after reading it.

Comment: *For example in Windows `'\n'` is converted to `"\r\n"` during I/O.* And what if you want to write a "Windows" file from non-Windows, or vice-versa? Basing your line endings based on the *current* platform is simply too unreliable to be a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

There is no such API in the standard library (there might be a crate for this, though). The simplest way to write lines to a file is with the [`writeln!`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/macro.writeln.html) macro and it only uses `\n` for newlines.

It was probably considered (by the Rust developers) not useful enough because I'm pretty sure that nowadays `\r\n` is used only for Microsoft Notepad compatibility.

There once was an [issue](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/19403) related to `write` not using `CRLF` on Windows, but it was concluded that:

> the raw `io::File` will likely not handle it by default but would instead require a wrapper

(note: since Rust 1.0 it is no longer `io::File`, but `fs::File`)

Comment: Are you saying all other apps in Windows now use "\n" only to terminate files?

Comment: I work in a system that requires `\r\n`, would be nice to be able to configure rust to do it automatically.